# Why are some of my custom posts not showing up on my page?

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, query-posts

I have 6 posts with a custom post type in my Wordpress theme. I want to show them all on a page but I can only get a maximum of 3 to show up, regardless of how many there are.

I have this code in the page:

```
<?php $count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'cases' )->publish;
echo $count_posts; ?>

<?php query_posts('post_type=cases'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post" style="display:inline;">case</div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

...and it outputs this:

```
6
case case case
```

Why are my other 3 custom posts not showing up?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't set a value for `posts_per_page`, it will use whatever the setting is for `Blog pages show at most` under `Settings > Reading`.

Also, [don't use `query_posts`, use WP_Query instead](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cases',
    'posts_per_page' => -1 // get all cases
);
$cases = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $cases->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $cases->have_posts() ) :
        $cases->the_post();
        // output case
    endwhile;
else:
    // nothing found
endif;
```